# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find 'id'=new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This was working properly before I added the answer scaffold. I was creating questions without any errors but now I keep on getting this
`Couldn't find Question with 'id'=new`

Did I mess the routes up when I created the nested resources?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
  get '/users/:id' => 'home#profile'
  resources :users
  resources :questions
  resources :answers

  resources :questions do
    resources :answers
  end
end
```

Answers controller:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_answer, only: [:destroy]

  def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = @question.answers.create(answer_params)
    @answer.username = current_user.username
    @answer.user_id = current_user.id
    @answer.avatar = current_user.avatar
    @answer.save!
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def destroy
    @answer.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def set_answer
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

The weird thing is, the error comes within the question controller and I haven't touched it all.

Question controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @questions = Question.all
    respond_with(@questions)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@question)
  end

  def new
    if user_signed_in?
      @question = current_user.questions.build
      respond_with(@question)
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @question = current_user.questions.build(question_params)
    if @question.save
      redirect_to question_path(@question)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @question.update(question_params)
    respond_with(@question)
  end

  def destroy
    @question.destroy
    respond_with(@question)
  end

  private
    def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:title, :description)
    end
end
```

The form that handles the question submission:

```
<div class="signin">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="well boxShadow">
            <div class="media">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="media-heading red">New Question</h4>
              <hr />
              <%= form_for(@question, url: new_question_path, html: { method: :put, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>

                <% if @question.errors.any? %>
                  <div id="error_explanation">
                    <h4><%= pluralize(@question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from being saved:</h4>

                    <ul>
                    <% @question.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                      <li><%= message %></li>
                    <% end %>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <% end %>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "form-control outline", :placeholder => "Enter your question" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <%= f.text_area :description, :class => "form-control outline", rows: 15 %>
                    </div>
                  </div>                

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.submit "Ask", :class => "btn btn-danger btn-md btn-block" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              <% end %>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Rake routes:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern
   Controller#Action
                 answers GET    /answers(.:format)
   answers#index
                         POST   /answers(.:format)
   answers#create
              new_answer GET    /answers/new(.:format)
   answers#new
             edit_answer GET    /answers/:id/edit(.:format)
   answers#edit
                  answer GET    /answers/:id(.:format)
   answers#show
                         PATCH  /answers/:id(.:format)
   answers#update
                         PUT    /answers/:id(.:format)
   answers#update
                         DELETE /answers/:id(.:format)
   answers#destroy
        question_answers GET    /questions/:question_id/answers(.:format)
   answers#index
                         POST   /questions/:question_id/answers(.:format)
   answers#create
     new_question_answer GET    /questions/:question_id/answers/new(.:format)
   answers#new
    edit_question_answer GET    /questions/:question_id/answers/:id/edit(.:form
t) answers#edit
         question_answer GET    /questions/:question_id/answers/:id(.:format)
   answers#show
                         PATCH  /questions/:question_id/answers/:id(.:format)
   answers#update
                         PUT    /questions/:question_id/answers/:id(.:format)
   answers#update
                         DELETE /questions/:question_id/answers/:id(.:format)
   answers#destroy
               questions GET    /questions(.:format)
   questions#index
                         POST   /questions(.:format)
   questions#create
            new_question GET    /questions/new(.:format)
   questions#new
           edit_question GET    /questions/:id/edit(.:format)
   questions#edit
                question GET    /questions/:id(.:format)
   questions#show
                         PATCH  /questions/:id(.:format)
   questions#update
                         PUT    /questions/:id(.:format)
   questions#update
                         DELETE /questions/:id(.:format)
   questions#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)
   devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)
   devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)
   devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)
   devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)
   devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)
   devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)
   devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)
   devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)
   devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)
   devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)
   devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)
   devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)
   devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)
   devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)
   devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /
   home#index
                         GET    /users/:id(.:format)
   home#profile
                   users GET    /users(.:format)
   users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)
   users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)
   users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)
   users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)
   users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)
   users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)
   users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)
   users#destroy
                         GET    /questions(.:format)
   questions#index
                         POST   /questions(.:format)
   questions#create
                         GET    /questions/new(.:format)
   questions#new
                         GET    /questions/:id/edit(.:format)
   questions#edit
                         GET    /questions/:id(.:format)
   questions#show
                         PATCH  /questions/:id(.:format)
   questions#update
                         PUT    /questions/:id(.:format)
   questions#update
                         DELETE /questions/:id(.:format)
   questions#destroy
```

Full trace:

```
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:320:in `raise_record_not_found_exception!'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:429:in `find_one'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:413:in `find_with_ids'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:68:in `find'
C:in `find'
app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:48:in `set_question'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:143:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:143:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: First thing I notice is that `:questions` and `:answers` are both defined twice in `routes.rb`. Try taking out the first copies and leaving the nested resources, if you want routes like `/questions/1/answers/1`.

Comment: @PJSCopeland I tried that earlier it didn't work

Comment: Generally this means you've ended up with `/questions/:id` above `/questions/new` in the routes. Your application will resolve a request using the first matching line in `rake routes`. However - *assuming* you're asking for `GET /questions/new` - that *should* resolve to `questions#new` according to what you've listed here, so I'm wondering if perhaps the request you're making is less obvious?

Comment: **Generally this means you've ended up with /questions/:id above /questions/new** That's exactly what's happening. It's searching for id=new instead of going to the normal `new_question_path`. But I honestly don't know what caused that error. I tried removing the additional duplicate resources but the error is still showing. Does that mean the problems lays outside the routes.rb?

Comment: If you tell me the **address of the request that's causing the error** I'll be able to track it...

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by that? I am still learning rails and the routes are still giving me confusion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104331/discussion-between-pjscopeland-and-raymond).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in this line here.

```
<%= form_for(@question, url: new_question_path, html: { method: :put, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

Between `new_question_path` and `method: :put`, the form is specifying that information should be returned over `PUT /questions/new`.

Here's the first line in `rake routes` that matches that:

```
PUT    /questions/:id(.:format)   questions#update
```

As you can see, that's not the route you want to return.

Assuming that `@question` has been constructed but not saved (as it would be in a standard `/new` request), I *think* Rails is clever enough to figure out everything you want from just this:

```
<%= form_for @question %>
```

(Especially if you're using this form in a partial that's also loaded from an `/edit` request.)

Otherwise, you'll need two different calls. Here's what you want to create a new form:

```
<%= form_for(@question, url: questions_path, html: { method: :post, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

... and here's what you want to update an existing one:

```
<%= form_for(@question, url: question_path(@question), html: { method: :put, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with this line

```
 def create
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])  <==================
  @answer = @question.answers.create(answer_params)
  @answer.username = current_user.username
  @answer.user_id = current_user.id
  @answer.avatar = current_user.avatar
  @answer.save!
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Rails is trying to find the question that you're adding the answer to. Although it's unable to find the question because the ID that is sent through is incorrect. It's receiving 'new' instead of i.e. 1, 2, 3.

The first thing I would try is putting the nested routes on top of the default resources. The order of the routes sometimes matters and it may be checking the default `resources :questions` instead of the nested routes

Try that, I'm gonna continue seeing if I can think of something else but that's the first thing I noticed.

EDIT:

By the way, I just checked the bottom of your rake routes, the questions#new should not be at the bottom. The default resources should always be above because it will find the first legit routes (questons/:id/answers/new) and will forget about the routes under that. So try to reorder them so that the questions#new is showing first in your rake routes.

EDIT 2: Sorry if my comments format is weird

type this into your routes

```
POST 'questions/new' => 'questions#new'
```

This will force your path to associate with a specific action.

Put it above all of the nesting and above the resources

Comment: go into your routes and manually type in

post 'questions/new' => 'questions#new'

You'll be forcing a route to associate with a specific action

If that doesn't work it's a problem with the new action inside of your controller

Comment: Also didn't work and I am using the generated scaffold code. I didn't change anything

Comment: Sometimes the generated routes get messed up with existing resources.
Hmm, I'm not sure. Hope you figure it out, goodluck!

Comment: WAIT! I think I know what's happening. You're using a private method that is looking for the ID of the question you're creating. This makes sense for updating the question but when you're creating a new question, that ID is non-existent, there for it will give you error in trying to find @questions in the 'questions#new' method.